# Efficiency of re-using PDOStatements for database calls in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Would it be efficient to save the PDOStatement returned by a prepare() to some class variable and then reuse that statement object rather than re-prepare when executing the same call?

```
Class QueryClass {
    public static $getSomeData;
}

Class Foo {

    $pdo = $pdo (PDO)
    $id;
    $first_name;
    $last_name;
    $email;
    $city;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, $id) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->id  = $id;
    }

    public function searchDB(Array $find) {

        $query  = "SELECT " . prepare_array($find);
        $query .= "FROM some_database ";
        $query .= "WHERE id = ?";

        // Option 1.) Prepare Normally
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

        // Option 2.) Prepare conditionally depending on what the query
        // was the last time the method was called. So it should only be called
        // when either (A) The method has never been called OR (B) The user
        // has changed the query string by entering different data in the
        // $find parameter

        if (!QueryClass::$getSomeData instanceof PDOStatement
            || QueryClas::$getSomeData->queryString != $query)
        {
            QueryClass::$getSomeData = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        }

        // Executing Option 1
        $statement->execute(Array($this->id));

        // Exectuting Option 2
        QueryClass::$getSomeData->execute(Array($this->id));  
    }
}

// And then using like this (I know that I havent actually created the PDO, just assume
// that I'm providing it). The second searchDB() call should use the same PDOStatement
// object created when the first object used it

$var  = new Foo($pdo, 5);
$var2 = new Foo($pdo, 10); 

$var->searchDB(Array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email'));
$var2->searchDB(Array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email'));

// Then makeing a call like this would cause the method to re-prepare the
// PDOStatement because the params provided are different

$var2->searchDB(Array('first_name', 'city'));
```

Is this more efficient than just preparing a new statement every time the query or method is called?

Comment: Looks good to me, but if you're not binding parameters, why bother preparing it? You could just execute it and let the query cache do its thing for repeated queries.

Comment: Good question. I believe that a look into the source code for the PDO library matching your RDBMS will show whither that module benefits from this.

Comment: Marcus - I would be binding params ... I just didn't include them because I was trying to make the example as simple as possible

Comment: I made an edit to the code to be a little more specific